# Number of distinct items in a List with ignoring one of the fields

Tags: c#, list

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Address { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int ID { get; set; } = 0;
}

public List<Person> ListOfPeople = new List<Person>();
```

Now let's have 2 `Person` objects:

- John Doe
- Boring St. 5
- 1

and

- John Doe
- Boring St. 5
- 2

These 2 entries in the `ListOfPeople` are NOT distinct to me.
I want to get number of distinct entries in `ListOfPeople` while ignoring the `ID` field. If I just do `Distinct()` it will treat those 2 objects as that (since ID is not the same).

Comment: You will either have to construct a new type without ID, and do distinct on that, or ignore that property and lose one of the objects (ie. the object with ID = 1 would win). Which one would you like to have?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen since I only want the number of said distinct objects, not the actual objects, which one wins is irreleveant I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an `IEqualityComparer<Person>` implementation that defines how you want the values to be compared. You can then use

```
var distinctByNameAndAddress = people.Distinct(comparer).ToList();
```

Your equality comparer would look something like this:

```
public sealed class NameAndAddressComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return x.Name == y.Name && x.Address == y.Address;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person person) =>
        ReferenceEquals(person, null) ? 0
        : 23 * person.Name.GetHashCode() + person.Address.GetHashCode();
}
```

Note that at the moment, you don't override `Equals`/`GetHashCode` or implement `IEquatable<Person>`, so even two objects with *all* properties the same would be seen as distinct.

Comment: Didn't know I can create my own comparer and how to do it, works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: It looks like `Distinct` doesn't check the values fur nullity, according to the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,856287389e9cace3).